# Why won't this CURL request work?

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api

I am trying post a comment on a YouTube video... To do this, I use the YouTube api. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$message="Just Some Comment...";
$developer_key="<!---visit demo for actual code---!>";
$access_token=$_GET['code'];
if(!$access_token ){ Header("Location: <!---visit demo for actual code---!>");}
$video_id="I3LMKhu2-vo";
$message_xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"     xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<content>' . $message . '</content>
</entry>'; 
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" . $video_id .  "/comments";
$header = array('Content-Type: application/atom+xml', 'Content-Length: ' .   strlen($message_xml), 'Authorization: Bearer "' . $access_token . '"', 'GData-Version: 2', 'X-GData-Key: key=' . $developer_key);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$message_xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $access_token;
?>
```

Where I reference `<!---visit demo for actual code---!>` that's to hide personal stuff, but you can see the demo at votm.net78.net. So my question is, why doesn't the comment appear on the video, even though the user has sent authorisation token?

Comment: What's in `$result`? What do you see if you put `var_dump($result);` after `$result = curl_exec($ch);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main thing that is missing is in your code is that you have to use the authorization code to get the real access_token by calling the token service (see Step 2 in my code). This means you'll have **two** curl requests in total. For details, have a look at the doc: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer?hl=de#handlingtheresponse

Furthermore, you need to create (unless already done) a project on https://code.google.com/apis/console/ to create a `Client ID` and `Client secret` for Authorized API Access. This is required in addition to the `developer key`.

With some additional error checking, I've cooked up the following code and have tested it successfully. I assume that the script is accessible via the URL

```
http://localhost/youtube.php
```

:

```
<?php

$developer_key='<!---hidden---!>';
$client_id=     '<!---hidden---!>';
$client_secret='<!---hidden---!>';

// error checking; user might have denied access
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    if ($_GET['error'] == 'access_denied') {
        echo('You have denied access. Click <a href="'. $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] .'">here</a> to retry&hellip;');
    } else {
        echo("An error has occurred: ". $_GET['error']);
    }
    exit;
}

// Step 1: redirect to google account login if necessary
if(!isset($_GET['code']) || $_GET['code'] === '') { 
    Header('Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id='. $client_id .
            '&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyoutube.php' .
            '&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline',
        true, 307);
    exit;
}
$authorization_code= $_GET['code'];

// Step 2: use authorization code to get access token
$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$message_post= 'code='. $authorization_code .
        '&client_id='. $client_id . 
        '&client_secret='. $client_secret .
        '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/youtube.php' .
        '&grant_type=authorization_code';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($cur_error= curl_error($ch)) {
    echo($cur_error);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

$jsonArray= json_decode($result, true);

if ($jsonArray === null) {
    echo("Could not decode JSON.");
    exit;
}

if (isset($jsonArray['error'])) {
    echo("An error has occurred: ". $jsonArray['error']);
    exit;
}

if (!isset($jsonArray['access_token'])) {
    echo("Access token not found.");
    exit;
}

// Step 3: using access_token for youtube api call
$message="Just Some Comment...";
$access_token= $jsonArray['access_token'];
$video_id="I3LMKhu2-vo";
$message_xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"     xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<content>' . $message . '</content>
</entry>'; 
$url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" . $video_id .  "/comments";
$header = array('Content-Type: application/atom+xml', 'Content-Length: ' .   strlen($message_xml), 'Authorization: Bearer "' . $access_token . '"', 'GData-Version: 2.1', 'X-GData-Key: key=' . $developer_key);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message_xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "DONE! Token:" . $access_token . "<br />\n";
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Note that the user who logs into his google account and on behalf on who the comment will be posted needs to have a linked YouTube account (google account alone is not enough). Besides, he needs to have posted at least one comment in YouTube successfully. Otherwise, he'll see an error like "youtube_signup_required" or "NoLinkedYouTubeAccount".

And I've switched to API 2.1 (GData-Version) since it is more recent and offers better functionality and error reporting in case of unlinked google accounts.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! I had to edit one or two lines because I got an error saying about "Header cannot have more than one line", but that's fixed! +50 rep coming your way, and thanks for your help!